# Update textfields to CoreData without destroying unchanged data

Tags: core-data, swiftui

When I change any textfield on my update form with new information ONLY that change is saved. All other previously saved data for the entity is lost in the process.

```
    func updateDog (
            id: String,
            dogName: String,
            activeStatus: Int16,
            breed: String,
            //etc  (about 30 attributes below here )

)
        {
            let fetchDog: NSFetchRequest<Dog> = Dog.fetchRequest()

            fetchDog.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
           
            do {

                let dog = try self.moc.fetch(fetchDog).first

                dog?.dogName = dogName
                dog?.activeStatus = activeStatus
                dog?.breed = breed
                //etc

if self.fetchDog(dogName: dogName)?.hasChanges ?? true {

                    try self.moc.save()
                }

            } catch
                let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
```

There are no errors messages, but any attributes already stored, which are left unchanged during the updating are lost in the self.moc.save process. Only the edited fields are updated.

I want it to ignore any attribute that has not been altered and simply update the changed data. I've been going around in circles but cannot achieve the correct behaviour. I am not very experienced as have only been learning to code for a few months, and my advancing years probably add to my struggles to grasp the problem I'm having. Any help is gratefully recieved

Comment: It's hard to say because the symptom you describe is not normal and there's nothing in your code snippet that would obviously cause it. It might help if you could edit the question to add more detail, including how you're calling this function (where does the `id` come from, and all the other fields?), how you're observing the problem, and any other details that seem relevant.

Comment: Need more code to analyse, especially SwiftUI part... I assume you need to store user input in some temporary object and only when all required fields filled then write/update database object.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and reassurance that the above code seems in order, I think now that the problem is that my form for updating isn't already preloaded with the saved attributes. So I've been looking at that this evening. But currently finding that harder than expected so may need to come back on that in a separate question.